# How can I dismantle this shower tap?

Tags: plumbing, shower, taps

The shower tap in the picture is, I think, a Hudson Reed shower control, similar to [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/ctm/Hudson-Reed-Tec-Twin-Concealed-Shower-Valve-with-Diverter-)

[image: Hudson Reed Shower tap]

Can anyone tell me how I can dismantle this as it is leaking and presumably needs a new washer? Also, I think the lower tap has some kind of lock which controls the hottest temperature (there is a small 'button' at approx. 3 o'clock on the lower tap). What is this called and how can it be adjusted?

**UPDATE**

I think this is the correct manual:

http://www.hudsonreed.co.uk/pdf/fitting-instructions/ULTRA_Twin_&_Triple_cw_Div_TWINTRIPDIV_Rev_0.pdf

I need to adjust the temperature as the shower is too cold with the temperature tap at full 'lock' (have tried both directions). It looks like page 7 describes how to do this but I cannot see the cartridge stop lug as described.

Comment: This [installation guide](http://www.ergonomicdesigns.co.uk/cms/Hudson_Reed_Shower_Valve_Fitting_Instructions.pdf) might be useful. The "button" on the lower tap *may* be a set screw holding the handle on, or the temperature control spindle. It looks to me like the handles may just pull off, and that the shroud may be fixed to the wall with silicone caulk.

Comment: @Tester101 So this seems to be the right manual http://www.hudsonreed.co.uk/pdf/fitting-instructions/ULTRA_Twin_&_Triple_cw_Div_TWINTRIPDIV_Rev_0.pdf but page 7 doesn't reflect what I see when I remove the taps and I wasn't able to turn the spline further anticlockwise